# STOP: 0x000000007E BSOD using OEM XP setup CD

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, setup

I get STOP: 0x000000007E BSOD using an OEM XP setup CD. It happens trying to go into Recovery Console or before reaching the EULA step.

Comment: Are you doing an install? Are you doing a recovery? More info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

XP SP2 worked. http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic16553.html

Answer (score 0):

What kind of storage controller do you have on that system? If it's anything other than a plain old IDE controller, try giving Windows proper drivers for it at the beginning of the setup process (by pressing F6).